# Do qualia have Being?

Tags: qualia, being

Do qualia have Being?

I'm unsure what 'Being' means, but take it that it has something to do with red always being red, self sameness or identity.

If qualia do have Being, is that itself like something, a quale? I think perhaps, because there is something it is like to see colours, to not be colourblind, and would guess there is no Being red for people that can't see it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93822/discussion-on-question-by-another-name-do-qualia-have-being).

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas There were two comments back and forth! A little quick on the trigger there friend.

Comment: Each reply counts as a separate comment. An extended exchange between two members does not count as two comments.